# "그대로 하세요" vs "이렇게 하세요."

Tags: grammar

• 그대로 하세요.
• 이렇게 하세요.

Both mean "do it like this", but I am told that they are used in different situations. Can you please explain the different situations these are used in and any other differences.

Comment: 그대로 하세요: Go on what you're doing. 이렇게 하세요:  follow the instruction given by me.

Comment: 그대로 하세요: 잘 하고 있으니 그렇게 하세요. 이렇게 하세요: 이것 어떻게 하나요? 이렇게 하세요. (The talker shows how to do that, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Let me show you some situations.

**Sit#1**

> A : 이것 어떻게 여나요?
>
> B : 이렇게 하세요.
>
> (B shows how to open the thing.)

**Sit#2**

> A: (A trying a way to open the thing) 이것 어떻게 여나요? 이렇게 열면 되나요?
>
> B: 네, 그렇게 하세요.
>
> (A successfully opens the thing.)

**Sit #1(Eng)**

> How can I open this?
>
> Let me show you.

**Sit #2(Eng)**

> How can I open this? Like this..?
>
> Yes, go ahead. You're right.

Hope this helped you understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

First, 그대로 frequently means "in the same way something was happening, without change."  For example:

> 그 차는 그대로 미끄러져서 벽을 들이받았다. = The car slipped right away (without changing course) and hit the wall.
>
> 계약은 그대로 유지하기로 합시다. = Let's keep the contract as-is.

So that's one thing you should keep in mind.

On the other hand, we can also look at 이/저/그 distinction, which appears in a lot of words:

- 이: something that's closer to the speaker
- 저: something that's distant from both (don't confuse with polite "I" which is also 저)
- 그: something that's closer to the listener, something from the past or remote location (basically, too far to see), or abstract concept

For example, here are situations where each is applicable:

- 이렇게 하세요: I am demonstrating something with my hands, and telling you to follow it.
- 저렇게 하세요: I am pointing to a third person, and telling you to follow him/her.
- 그렇게 하세요:

  - I am pointing to what *you* are doing (or responding to what you just said), and saying that you can do it that way.
  - Or, we are talking about how it was done before, or the instruction we just read.

Finally, "이렇게" is an adverb meaning "in this way", while "이대로" is made of "이"(this) + "대로" (usually means "following"), so can be thought of as "following this (method/instruction/etc.)".  So they are interchangeable in many places.  Same for 저렇게/저대로 or 그렇게/그대로.